# Problems with some Arduino code

Tags: arduino

So, I was building an Arduino project that I saw on the internet (reddit message notifier), and I downloaded the code, but there are weird problems with the variables...  I don't know much Arduino code.  I can't seem to figure out the problem.  Thanks in advance!  Here is the program code:

Edit:  It doesn't compile (the Arduino application on the computer doesn't compile things that won't work). It says something about an int not being able to be a const char*. Or something like that. I don't remember exactly. I'll be able to post the complete error when I get to my computer soon.

```
#include <String.h>;
#include "pitches.h"


//define our variables
int ledPin = 11;
int x = 0;
int oldbreathe;
int slot;
String incomingWord, incomingByte, breathe, postscore;


//defines the melody played and the duration of each note
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int melody[] = {
NOTE_G4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_D6, NOTE_G5, NOTE_GS4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_DS7, NOTE_GS5, NOTE_AS5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_F6, NOTE_AS5};
int noteDurations[] = {
32, 32, 32, 32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,16 };
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////






void setup() {
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600); 
breathe = 49;
slot    = 1;
}


void loop() {

if (breathe == 49){ // if (breathe = 1) then start breathe math function
int outVal = yforx(x);
analogWrite(ledPin, outVal);
delay(6); // modify the pace of breathing
x++;
}
if (breathe == 48){
analogWrite(ledPin, 0); // override the LED to OFF if (breathe = 0)
}

/////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////

if (Serial.available() > 0) { //If we get a character over the serial line (serial activity)
incomingByte = Serial.read();  

if (incomingByte == 44){  //44 we received a delimiting comma. dump incomingWord to open array slot
  if (slot > 2){
    slot=1;
  }


  if (slot == 1){
    breathe = incomingWord;
    //        Serial.print("new breathe value: ");
    //        Serial.println(breathe);
    if (breathe == 49){playmusic();}
    slot++;


  }
  else 
    if (slot == 2){
    postscore = incomingWord;
    Serial.print("new postscore value: ");
    Serial.println(postscore);
    slot++;
  }


  incomingWord = "";
 }


else if (incomingByte != 13){ //received normal character. add to word
  incomingWord = incomingWord + incomingByte;
}

else 
  if (incomingByte == 13){  //13 is carriage return
  slot = 1;
  incomingWord = "";

}
} 
}


void playmusic() {
for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 12; thisNote++) {
int noteDuration = 1000/noteDurations[thisNote];
tone(8, melody[thisNote],noteDuration);
int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
noTone(8); 
} 
}



int yforx(int x) {
return (-240*abs(sin(x*0.01)))+255; //sine wav`
```

Comment: What is your error? What problems are you having? You have provided almost no detail for this question

Comment: What is happening? We have to know where your code crashes.

Comment: It doesn't compile (the Arduino application on the computer doesn't compile things that won't work).  It says something about an int not being able to be a const char*.  Or something like that.  I don't remember exactly.  I'll be able to post the complete error when I get to my computer in about an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your string and character handling. You have declared `int oldbreathe;` and `String incomingWord, incomingByte, breathe, postscore;` yet you are treating incomingByte and breathe as ints. You can get it to compile by using

```
String incomingWord;
int incomingByte, postscore;
int breathe;
```

and rather than having `breathe = incomingWord;` use

```
    breathe = incomingWord.charAt(0);
```

in the two places it occurs. While it compiles I'm not sure if it will work as i don't really understand what sort of input you are expecting. The code looks quite convoluted but it is quite tricky handeling the input one byte at a time. I suggest reading about the String class at http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject.